# How do I store a value that could be multiple data types?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating a new model "detail" and along with other attributes I want to have a "value" attribute.

Thing is depending on the detail the value could be a number or a string or a Boolean.

My first instinct would be to just use a string and cast the value to another type later.

If I did this would it be wise to use another column like value_type to store what type the value should be for the purpose of casting later.

Am I overlooking a more conventional "Rails way" of doing things here?

Comment: There's always serialization.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure at the moment. My feeling is that a string could suffice but I wanted to keep my options open.

Comment: Which database do you have in mind?

Comment: Why don't you store it as string and when you want to access it, you try to convert it using rescue clauses? so method `to_right_object` would return boolean, string, or maybe number

Comment: I am using postgreSQL in production but still using sqlite in development. I know postgreSQL has the h_store type that sounds similar but preferable to serialization. If I am understanding the serialization concept correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize attribute

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :value
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this save the value as a collection eg. `Hash` or `Array`?

Comment: Only if you put Hash or Array as second parameter